# Ceasar Cipher In C not outputing correctly past 100 iterations

Tags: c, encryption, ascii

I'm working on an assignment for class so I would prefer for you to assist me in the matter or rather point me in the right direction rather than just giving me an answer. That being said my program encrypts a string based on a Ceasar Cipher (This is not by any means secure it is merely a simple program). When it runs through encoding and decoding the result is find and never has any issues assuming the number of passes (or rather number of times I encrypt it) is less than 100. When the encode and decode are over 100 passes I get a different string than expected as an output for my encode, and my decode only outputs a single character (the first).

This is the code and note it is intentional that the output is not within the normal ascii range as that is what the assignment asks.

```
enum CODE_METHOD {ENCODE, DECODE};  
int mystrlen(const unsigned char *string)
{
  int length = 0;
  int index;

  for(index = 0;*(string+index) != 0; index++)
    length++;

  return length;
}

void jumble(unsigned char *string, 
            const unsigned char *password, 
            enum CODE_METHOD method, 
            int passes)
{
  int index, index_2;
  int len = mystrlen(password);

  for(index_2 = 0; index_2 < passes; index_2++)
    for(index=0; *(string+index) != '\0'; ++index )
      *(string+index) += (method == ENCODE) ?   *(password+(index % len)) 
                                            : - *(password+(index % len));
}
```

Also here is an example driver which would call this

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf, putchar                  */
#include "jumble.h" /* mystrlen, jumble, ENCODE, DECODE */

void test_stress(int passes)
{
  unsigned char phrase[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  unsigned char *password = (unsigned char*) "rumpelstiltskin";
  size_t length = sizeof(phrase);
  size_t i;

  printf("\nStress ======================================\n");
  printf("Original phrase:\n");
  printf("%s\n", phrase);
  jumble(phrase, password, ENCODE, passes);

  printf("\nEncoded phrase:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    putchar(phrase[i]);

  jumble(phrase, password, DECODE, passes);
  printf("\nDecoded back:\n");
  printf("%s\n", phrase);
}

int main(void)
{
  test_stress(100);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the expected output of the above driver:

```
Stress ======================================
Original phrase:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Encoded phrase:
Éö×¹v3˜Mz›8RGØæÈ…B§\‰ª 
Decoded back:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Recieved output

```
Stress ======================================
Original phrase:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Encoded phrase:
É Ñä£Îù ¿ÒþÏÄãPD ³  ÇÈ 
Decoded back:
A
```

Again I would like to be pointed in the right direction here

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem but you should use `a[i]` instead of `*(a+i)` for array accesses as it's much more readable.

Comment: Normal Ceaser Cipher uses only ascii chars (only English letters, really. You might want to specify what exactly is your code about. Besides, give a better description of your input and desired output compared to the one you get.

Comment: Thats fair enough I will take that into account Thank you!

Comment: @Neo I added an example

Comment: And what output do you actually get?

Comment: Do you keep re-encoding the same already encoded message 100 times, and then decode it 100 times to arrive back where you started? Does any encoded character have a `0` value in it causing string truncation? You don't pass a length but detect the `0` terminator.

Comment: The combination of `*(string+index) != '\0'` and `*(string+index) += ...` looks problematic. You keep adding to the characters with no modulo. You could be overflowing `char` and ending up with a 0 for a character. I would try restricting to ASCII like Neo said. Something like `string[i] = (string[i] + your_shift) % 26 + 65` (and minus for decoding) would restrict to capital English letters.

Comment: I tried fixing it that way and got it outputting the correct thing except rolled right ("LMNOPQRTSTUVWXYZABCD..."). Maybe there's another problem I'm not seeing.